# BCP Export Login Failed for User NT Authority/Anonymous Logon

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server is online and I'm trying to export data to a remote server. I'm using Windows Authentication to log on sql server.

Code:

```
declare @sql1 varchar(8000), @asofdate varchar(50)

set @asofdate = convert(varchar,getdate()-1,112) + '.csv'

select @sql1 = 'bcp DB1.dbo.Table1 out C:\exp\test' + @asofdate  + ' -c -t, -T -S'+ '.\SQL2005'
exec master.. xp_cmdshell @sql1
```

but I get error

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

If I try

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'del C:\exp\*.csv'
```

The code works fine. So I think I do have access to `xp_cmdshell`.

Then I wonder why my `xp_cmdshell` doesn't work for `bcp` export?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing off a command to an external application.

This external application doesn't really know you, or where your command came from. Hence the `ANONYMOUS LOGON` message.

You need to tell the command who to execute as. Have a look at BCP in BoL (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) and you'll spot a few parameters that you might wish to add:

**-T** 
*Specifies that the bcp utility connects to SQL Server with a trusted connection using integrated security. The security credentials of the network user, login_id, and password are not required. If –T is not specified, you need to specify –U and –P to successfully log in.*

**-U *login_id***
*Specifies the login ID used to connect to SQL Server.*

**-P *password***
*Specifies the password for the login ID. If this option is not used, the bcp command prompts for a password. If this option is used at the end of the command prompt without a password, bcp uses the default password (NULL).*

Comment: I think you are right. I've created a new login "user001", and assigns sysadmin role to it, and added the user to my db, somehow I got error saying Login failed for user 'user001' when I execute the bcp sp with -U user001 -P XXXX

Comment: while I can log on to the sql server use "user001" and the same password XXXX

Comment: What's the value of `PRINT @sql1`? Consider `... -S ' + @@ServerName`

Comment: it's bcp DB1.dbo.Table1 out C:\exp\test20140914.csv -c -t, -Uuser001 -P XXXX -S .\SQL2005

Comment: Do you get a different error? I find that debugging this kind of thing is best done on the commandline itself. Start > Run > CMD. Start tip-tapping your BCP commands directly in there. *Prove* your command string is correct. Then take that *exact* command string, and play with it in T-SQL. Only when you've done both of these things should you move on to dynamic SQL `:-)`

Comment: Thank you! When I switched to a different password, it works now. My original password is in a wierd format.